# How Do I Loop through Worksheet and Detect Duplicate Lines based on Certain Column Values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that will loop through a worksheet to detect duplicate lines in a product log. I need it to look at the UPC (Column A), Expiration Date (Column E), and Location (Column H).

I have the first loop running from 2 to LastRow which is the value of `srcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. I assign variables the values of Range A/E/H:x and then have a second loop running from LastRow to 3 with a -1 step.

The problem I am having is that when I add a second condition, using either `And` or a nested `If/Then`, every line will match. I have that `MsgBox` output a message and show me the values of `x` and `y`.

If I am only checking one pair of values, like `chkUPC` and `srcUPC`, I will see everything fine. When I add the second condition, `chkExpDate = srcExpDate`, it will find every line is a duplicate and when I output the values of `x` and `y`, they will match so rather than comparing Row 2 to Row 1950 for the first run, it will be comparing row 3 to iteself.

Here is the code:

```
srcLastRow = srcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 2 To srcLastRow
        srcUPC = srcSheet.Range("A" & x).Value
        srcExpDate = srcSheet.Range("E" & x).Value
        srcQty = srcSheet.Range("G" & x).Value
        srcLocation = srcSheet.Range("H" & x).Value
        
        For y = srcLastRow To 3 Step -1
            
            chkUPC = srcSheet.Range("A" & y).Value
            chkExpDate = srcSheet.Range("E" & y).Value
            chkQty = srcSheet.Range("G" & y).Value
            chkLocation = srcSheet.Range("H" & y).Value
            
            If chkUPC = srcUPC And chkExpDate = srcExpDate Then
                    MsgBox "The same product has been found on multiple lines" & vbCrLf & x & " | " & y
            End If

        Next y
    Next x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
For y = srcLastRow To 3 Step -1
```

to

```
For y = srcLastRow To x+1 Step -1
```

otherwise it will compare every line except the second one with itself.